# Should I refer to SE topics as "topic.se" or "topic@se"

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, terminology

As I've realized on [this meta post](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/713/24224) at the RPi SE, there are multiple `.se` domains that are ambiguous with the SEs on the site. I frequently see people refer to stacks as "Topic.SE" (*RPi.se* for example).

When I saw that the user that posted that answer on the linked post use `rpi.se` instead of `rpi@se`, I realized that people might mistakenly literally go to [http://rpi.se](http://rpi.se/)

Here's a few more examples of ambiguous `.se` domains:

```
rpi.se
aviation.se
chess.se
academia.se
so.se (StackOverflow I guess)
beer.se
drupal.se
law.se
photography.se
webmasters.se
```

Should I/we encourage everyone to use "Topic.SE" or "Topic@SE"?

Comment: Webmasters SE. Note the space and lack of punctuation.

Comment: Not that in comments,  magic links employing the dot/period notation, e.g. `[Law.SE]` and `[Chess.SE]`, do resolve to the Stack in question, as in [Law.se] and [Chess.se] . By contrast, the `@` character is reserved for pinging users.